# Balanced output from interface to unbalanced RCA speakers

Tags: cable

I'm currently looking to get the Focusrite Scarlett Solo 3rd Gen interface, from what I see they have 1/4" balanced outputs.

My current PC speakers have RCA inputs, can I use a TS to RCA adapter to connect the balanced output of the interface with the unbalanced input of the speakers? Would this harm the interface or the speaker?

Comment: 'Balance' speakers, their inputs and outputs, don't exist. balancing happens on the input into the pre-amp. It just happens that trs are sometimes referred to as 'balanced jacks'. Phono to jack will be fine.

Comment: In the context of music-tech, 'Speaker' now implies 'powered speaker'.   An output, a cable and an amplifier can all be balanced.  And to have a 'balanced' connection, they all must be!

Answer (score 1):

A simple adapter will be just fine.  It is common in this type of equipment for a balanced output on a TRS jack to fall back to unbalanced when a TS plug is inserted.

Comment: Exactly right, and in fact I know that particular audio interface well and its manual clearly says that its two balanced outputs can be used either way (TRS balanced and TS unbalanced).